# Converting WPF Datatemplates using x:Type to Silverlight

Tags: wpf, silverlight, datatemplate

I have a WPF app that uses x:type when working with datatemplates. 
This doesn't work in Silverlight out of the box, but I can remember that I saw something some time ago in a googlegroup where they where talking about Silverlight Extensions and how that could be used.

If anyone knows what I am talking about or knows how I can reuse my datatemplates in silverlight and has some nice samplecode you would make my day.

/johan

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago... and I have found a solution... I am not very proud of it but it works..
create a datatemplate and add there all the possible usercontrols

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="WorkspaceItemTemplate">
            <Grid>
                <View:TreeView Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=TreeView}" />
                <View:GridView Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=GridView}" />
                <View:DataView Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ViewVisibilityConverter}, ConverterParameter=DataView}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
```

and create a convertor that changes visibility based on type

```
 public class ViewVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (((ViewModelBase)value).DisplayName.Equals((string)parameter))
                return Visibility.Visible;
            return Visibility.Collapsed;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, this is not really a very good solution as your hidden controls still hang around in the background and consume resources. I think the best way to do this is via a template selector.

Answer (score 1):

This was finally fixed in Silverlight 5. You can write this sort of thing now:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="loc:MyType">
    <TextBlock Text="My template" />
</DataTemplate>
```

You can put that in a resource dictionary without needing to specify an x:Key.

Note that Silverlight doesn't support the x:Type attribute so you'll need to specify just the type name, without the markup extension, as Muad'Dib mentions (although his suggestion didn't actually work back when he wrote it back in 2009 - Silverlight's DataTemplate didn't even have a DataType property until December 2011).

Answer (score 0):

in silverlight, you leave off the x:Type and drop the braces... like this....

```
<Style TargetType="local:TemplatedControl">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:TemplatedControl">
                    <StackPanel x:Name="Panel" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm using MMVM so I dynamically load objects and want the UI to display the right view depending on type. Does youor solution still solve my problem??

Comment: take your WPF xaml and replace the {x:Type .... }, remove the braces, remove the x:Type and you should be good to go.  silverlight is a bit different, so you might have to make template selectors or such.